# How to dismiss multiple view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I've created mainview for call gallery view.

create main view and call gallery view in this code.

```
 GalleryView *GalView=(GalleryView *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SBGallery"];
 [self presentViewController:GalView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

after select photo in gallery view and  call crop photo this code.

```
CropView *CropView=(CropView *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SBCrop"];
[self presentViewController:CropView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

How to close cropview and goto mainview (close cropview and galleryview in single method)??

thank you for advance.

Comment: how do you able to present second view controller on already presented controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like,

```
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

    [previousVC presentViewController:cropVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

you have to take one property(say `previousVC`) in gallery vc and when you present galery vc assign self to it(previousVC).

then when you will dismiss `cropVC` your `galleryVC` will not there as you have already dismissed it!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a method like this in `CropView`

```
func dismissToMainViewController() {
  self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
  }
}
```